# How can I mock `networkError` vs `graphQLErrors` in storybook with apollo?

Tags: error-handling, apollo-client, storybook, storybook-addon

I'm using Storybook with an Apollo graphql frontend. The component I'm creating stories for treats the graphql `networkError` differently from `graphQLErrors`. In the Storybook apollo client add-on [documentation](https://storybook.js.org/addons/storybook-addon-apollo-client)
there is an example of mocking an error:

```
import DashboardPage, { DashboardPageQuery } from '.';

export default {
  title: 'My Story',
};

export const Example = () => <DashboardPage />;

Example.parameters = {
  apolloClient: {
    mocks: [
      {
        request: {
          query: DashboardPageQuery,
        },
        error: new Error('This is a mock network error'),
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

But this is always treated as a `networkError` as far as I can tell. Is there a way to create separate mock responses for `graphQLErrors` and `networkError`?